# InfoPath Form Library makes cpu usage high to 99%

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, cpu

After updating SharePoint 2013 with the related service pack we have some issues with CPU Usage. There is an InfoPath Form Library that when the user starts to open it the CPU usage will go up to 99% and the form stays in loading and opening.

I tried to optimize the form's data connections but the problem did not solve. I also checked the worker processes in IIS Manager(as the IIS Process gets the most of CPU) and there is some logs :

[image: Work Process]

Comment: Yes it does indeed , depends on RAM , mine is 8gb and it runs like butter

Comment: Thanks ViperOrton but I did not get what you mean. You are saying that is the RAM issue? we have Front-End web and our SQL Server is on another server. It has the RAM issue but why it should effect on this form only?

Comment: Server works are always slow, but it is for every form not any individual i guess.

Comment: I agree. It seems to be an strange issue with just InfoPath Form Library. I dont know what to do :(